# Can I use a resistor in place of a transformer?

Tags: voltage

Why is a step-down transformer used instead of a resistor for reducing high voltage?  For example: If input voltage is 230V and I have step down the voltage, can I use a resistor instead of transformer? If I cant, can any one explain the drawbacks?

Answer (score 16):

Think of a transformer like a speed reduction gear box - high speed, low torque in and low speed, high torque out.

Think of a resistor like a constantly slipping clutch - it burns power to reduce speed.

Answer (score 8):

Ideal resistors dissipate power as heat to drop voltage.

Ideal transformers don't have power losses to transfer to a lower voltage (real transformers do due to winding resistance and core losses, but these are typically significantly less than resistors).

Additionally, the voltage drop of a resistor is dependent on the load impedance/current draw while transformers are generally immune to this.

Answer (score 2):

How much a resistor drops voltage is dependent on how much current is flowing through it ([Ohm's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ohm%27s_law)). As loads are often variable, this means that the voltage drop will be variable as well. There are a number of applications where a variable supply voltage is unacceptable for various reasons.

If you are looking to build a transformer-less power supply then you should look at [capacitive drop supplies](http://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/AND8146-D.PDF), where the charging curve of a capacitor is used in conjunction with a zener diode to restrict voltage to a maximum level. *But keep in mind that capacitive drop supplies lack the isolation that a transformer provides, and as such are **highly dangerous** for inexperienced electronics students and they should **not** attempt to build one.*

Comment: Personally I'd rather NOT have Rahul look at non-isolated power supplies!

Comment: @WoutervanOoijen: Disclaimer added.